# Parameter pack passed by reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I wrote a simple variadic template function and I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work. (Its output counterpart works perfectly.)

```
#include <iostream>

void read() {}

template<class curr_t, class... rest_t>
void read(curr_t &var, rest_t... rest)
{
    std::cin >> var;
    read(rest...);
}

int main()
{   
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

    read(a, b, c); //input: 1 2 3
    std::cout << a << b << c; //output: 1 0 0

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

As can be seen from the comments, I input `1 2 3` for `a b c` and the output I get is `1 0 0`. As it is apparent, only `a` saves its value. Can someone explain why this happens and what can I do to fix it? Thanks!

EDIT::
Yes, apparently I had the concept of parameter packs wrong!
I was also trying to do the following: `rest_t... &rest` which gives me a compiler error.

Instead if I write `rest_t&... rest` it works as intended. I suppose it was just a syntax error on my side! Thanks to whoever posted this as an answer and deleted his answer a minute later! D:

Comment: Maybe it has to do with `rest` being passed by value?

Comment: Don't you think function `read` recurses infinitely?

Comment: But as I understand it, as the parameter pack "unpacks", the first element (in this case) of the pack becomes curr_t &var.

Comment: @vishal Why would it recurse infinitely?

Comment: @vishal This is why `read()` is there, to capture calling `read` with zero arguments which will eventually happen when `rest...` is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` is passed by reference but the others are copied: when you call it recursively, they are, yes, taken by reference, but they refer to a variable previously passed by value so it won't be modified externally.

```
template<class curr_t, class... rest_t>
void read(curr_t &var, rest_t&... rest)
//                           ^               
{
    std::cin >> var;
    read(rest...);
}
```